# How to use PHP/MSQLI to update a DB record and stay on the same page as the passed through variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have been searching for a while now and have not been able to find anything that works. My two majors problems are the following:

1) Update record
2) After the record is updated, Post the same record back to the page.

PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) { // checks for id
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //check if submit is selected
        if (is_numeric($_POST['id'])) { //validates the id


            if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare($con,"UPDATE hdd_tracking Set 
            ticket = ?,
            serial = ?,
            vol_name = ?,
            drivetype = ?,
            project = ?,
            notes = ?,
            encrypt_date =?,
            encryption_password = ?,
            fedX_tracking = ?,
            fedX_rt_tracking = ?,
            where id = ?
            ")){
                $stmt -> bind_param(
                "issssssssss",
                $_POST['ticket'],
                $_POST['serial'],
                $_POST['vol_name'],
                $_POST['drivetype'],
                $_POST['project'],
                $_POST['notes'],
                $_POST['encrypt_date'],
                $_POST['encryption_password'],
                $_POST['fedX_tracking'],
                $_POST['fedX_rt_tracking']);

                $stmt ->execute();
                $stmt -> close();
            } else{
            die ("Error. Could not prepare SQL statement.");
            }
        }
        header('location:/pdsdashboard.com/it_services/hdd_tracking/index.php');
    }   
}
```

The form is a generic one.

```
<form class="form-inline insertDrive" role="form" name="update" method="post" action="review.php">
<table style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4" border="0" style="background-color: #F1E7CD;">
                <label class="col-sm-2">ID: <?php echo $_GET['id'];?><label>                    
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr align="left">
        <td>
            <label class="center">Ticket:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ticket" id="ticket" placeholder="Ticket">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="center">Volume Name:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vol_name" id="vol_name" placeholder="Volume Name">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="center">Type:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="drivetype" id="drivetype" placeholder="Type">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="center">Project:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="project" id="project" placeholder="Project">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="center">Encryption:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="encryption_password" id="encryption_password" placeholder="Encryption">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="center">Date:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="encrypt_date" id="encrypt_date" placeholder="Date">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>Serial:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="serial" id="serial" placeholder="Serial">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="center">Tracking:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fedX_tracking" id="fedX_tracking" placeholder="Tracking">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="center">Return:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fedX_rt_tracking" id="fedX_rt_tracking" placeholder="Return">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="center">Notes:</label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="notes" id="notes" placeholder="Notes" style="width:100%;"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-info" id="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Store `$_GET['id']` into `$_SESSION['id']` so that your `id` persists through page requests. Overwrite the `$_SESSION['id']` when the `$_GET['id']` is not empty, and check for `$_SESSION['id']`.

Comment: Are these 2 seperate scripts or bit of the same script

Comment: Two separate scripts on the same page. The reason why the second has significance in my opinion is that the I am using the $_GET['id'] function. However, allow me clarify what I am trying to do. When the data is updated it will not refresh the page and the id is no longer present. I would like to keep the same id present on the page so that when there is an update done, the data will be able to show for the same record with the new updated information.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in here:

```
header('location:/pds029/pdsdashboard/it_services/hdd_tracking/');
```

You are sending your user to a page but you have not told the page to pass the GET parameter.

Try something like this:

```
header('location:/pds029/pdsdashboard/it_services/hdd_tracking/?id='.$_GET['id']);
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. I just tried it an no luck. However, the ID is already being passed through from another page without issue and it will display once on the review/update page. However, it is only when the form is submitted does the passed through ID get dropped and it becomes an unidentified value.